# Spring AuthenticationManager StackOverflowError with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, authentication, spring-security, stack-overflow, autowired

I have SecurityConfig for my application on Kotlin with Spring. So when I try to authenticate I get java.lang.StackOverflowError: null. I found it returns when runs this:

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword()));
```

So this is my config.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig() : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

@Override
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
}

@Bean
fun passwordEncoder(): BCryptPasswordEncoder? = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

@Override
@Bean
override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager = 
super.authenticationManagerBean()
}
```

Ant this is exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.lang.String.equals(String.java:1827) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.isEqualsMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:514) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.isEqualsMethod(AopUtils.java:151) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:167) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy99.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy99.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy99.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
```

I found a lot of same problems but none of them have helped me.
Where the problem is?

The same config on Java work correctly

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved my problem.
A basic authenticationManager check username and password

```
   fun createAuthToken(@RequestBody authRequest: JwtRequest): ResponseEntity<Any?> {
   try {
   authenticationManager.authenticate(
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
   authRequest.username,
   authRequest.password
   ))
```

So it is necessary authenticationManager to know how to check username and password. We should override special method loadUserByUsername in UserService and make UserService extends UserDetailsService like this/

```
enter code here
@Override
@Transactional
override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): UserDetails {
val user: User = findByUsername(username) ?: throw 
UsernameNotFoundException(("User ${username} not found"))
return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
user.userName,
user.password,
mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles())
)}
```